# Drawing on the backside of a WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have quite an uncommon question: Does anyone know whether it is possible to draw something on the backside of a WPF Window?

Normally people create Controls or draw images on the front side of a WPF Window. However, I would like to draw things on the backside. Here is an Image taken with the [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) tool. Snoop has the functionality of viewing a WPF Application in 3D. Using the so-called **Zoomer** it is possible to look *behind* a window.[image]

I would like to either draw an Image or put a Control so that you can see it with using the Zoomer functionality of snoop at the back of the application.

Has anyone got an idea of how this could be done?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: This question.  Its kinda goofy.

Comment: There is no back side (or spoon)

Comment: @Paolo - Are you sure? I've seen custom controls which can flip - or at least it looks like they flip

Comment: @Christian - I think you need to use WPF's 3D capabilities to have a 'backside' of a control. I don't think the concept can exist with the two dimensional controls. As far as viewing the 'backside' in snoop, I suppose it all depends on whether or not snoop was designed to handle 3D WPF controls. If it is. I'd imagine it works just fine.

Comment: @Scott - that sounds to me like Snoop is just drawing these gray backsides because the Foreground is gray as well. So in reality there does not exist a backside, but Snoop just creates one because it looks nicer (if viewed from behind or from the side). That's good. I will look into the 3D libraries available. Thanks.

Comment: Windows on the screen don't have backsides. They're not like real windows. You can't actually touch them, either. I think you're taking the metaphor too far.

Comment: @Christian - I think you're right. Snoop is likely just using the 3D libraries itself and slapping each of your controls on one of the faces. You've now got me curious, however, if and how snoop handles objects already in 3D. Would be pretty cool to see if it does!

Comment: @Scott - I will write a little app containing a 3D cube or something and see what it does.

Comment: @Scott - Very disappointing result... I have implemented a small application drawing a 3d-polyhedron and Snoops just sees a triangle. I think that would also mean that drawing things on the backside does not work.

Comment: @Christian - That's a bummer, sounds like it only handles/displays a single plane and then renders its own 3D based on the Z-Index of controls on that plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no backside.

What most applications do is simply replace the control/window by another one as soon as it has rotated by 90 degrees.

Comment: I see. That's what I feared. So I will have to look into 3D libraries as Scott said in his comment. Thanks

Comment: My suggested solution is quite easy in Silverlight  because of the PlaneProjections. I bet we'll have those in the next version of WPF